# Oracle Database gather metrics during load test

Tags: oracle, testing, load, monitoring

I am load testing a web application and wondering if there is a way I can get the health of the my oracle database during the load test. Any idea or links to articles is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the Oracle version, whether you are licensed to use the AWR (Automatic Workload Repository), or whether you have Statspack installed, a first pass would be to take a snapshot before and after your test and run an AWR or Statspack report.  That will show you what the system was waiting on, how much of the elapsed time was due to database waits, top SQL statements, etc.

The Performance and Tuning Guide for your version of Oracle should have a chapter or two on using either AWR or Statspack.  For example, in 10.2, there is a section on [managing snapshots in the AWR](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/autostat.htm#i26958) and on [generating AWR reports](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/autostat.htm#i35176)

Answer (score 2):

If the licensing permits, AWR is the way to go. As @Justin mentions, you can start AWR< do the first run and have a baseline against which you can refer to. AWR allows you to create, store and preserve custom snapshots across different timelines - and this has saved me lots of time in trying to find where my wait times are.

If you're looking at real-time monitoring, the Enterprise Manager console also gives a wealth of information.

[This article](http://awads.net/wp/2009/11/15/oracle-performance-monitoring-in-less-than-12-minutes-video/) provides some good insight.

( pardon the bad quality of image )

[image]